# request.getParameter("xyz") always returns null in POST method - tomcat 7

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

I just upgraded my servlet container apache tomcat from version 6 to 7.
My application breaks after the server is started as `request.getParameter("xyz")` always `returns null` 
and my code won't proceed if it encounters null parameter.
It was working fine with **apache-tomcat-6.0.33**. No other changes was made in the application(mappings and all are done).
Also the application was deployed in the newer tomcat version, in the application environment(not in local machine or eclipse).

**Note:-**
We have an underlying framework, which is called Comergent. A jsp submits the forms and controller invokes another jsp to reneder these parameters.
When printed all the `request.getParameter("xyz")` values from the second jsp, ALL are returning `NULL`. The issue exists only for POST method, it is working fine with GET.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sharon M P

Comment: Some more infos would be appreciated, as it's difficult to tell something without code. For example, did you deploy the application or you're trying to run it under eclipse?

Comment: Give us the URL that is invoked and the Servlet that handles the invocation.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. There was an exception due to which the parameters were all null. It was page not found 404 exception. When this particular issue was resolved, the parameters were not reset (to null) anymore and those retained the exact values.